# "Trying to free invalid pointer" error detected in destructor

Tags: c++

I am in the beginning stages of writing a fairly large code. I have defined one class as such:

```
class GPUMD {
    private:
        double xhi, xlo, yhi, ylo, zhi, zlo;
        int numAtoms;
        Atom *atoms;
    public:
        GPUMD();
        ~GPUMD();
};
```

The destructor is defined as below:

```
GPUMD::~GPUMD() {
    if(atoms != NULL)
        delete [] atoms;
}
```

Right now, the code does this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GPUMD gpumd;
    exit(0);
}
```

I get a glibc detected error: trying to free invalid pointer. Using valgrind, I see that this error traces to my destructor for GPUMD. For some reason, the atoms != NULL test is returning true even though I have not assigned anything to that pointer. Why is that?

EDIT: The constructor is defined as:

```
GPUMD::GPUMD() {}
```

Comment: Please show the constructor too.

Comment: Note, that you can omit comparation with `NULL` before deleting, because deleting null pointer is valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `atoms` has not been explicitly initialised to `NULL` or a valid pointer in the constructor. Change constructor to:

```
GPUMD::GPUMD() : numAtoms(0), atoms(NULL) {}
```

Note that the `atoms != NULL` check prior to the `delete[]` is superfluous as `delete[]`, or `delete`, on a `NULL` pointer is no-op. The following is safe:

```
GPUMD::~GPUMD() {
    delete [] atoms;
}
```

As there is a dynamically allocated member in `GPUMD` you need to prevent copying of instances of `GPUMD` or implement the assignment operator and copy constructor (see [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)).

As C++, consider using a `vector<Atom>` (or a `vector` of smart pointers) instead which will manage dynamic memory for you.

Comment: The unguarded `delete[]` is not a good idea generally, since the pointer might get deleted elsewhere. Without explicitly making sure to set it to NULL again in such cases, this would result in a double `delete[]`.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras, just because a pointer is not `NULL` does not guarantee that it points to a valid object, as this question nicely shows. Having a guarded delete does provide a 100% guarantee and neither does `NULL`ing a pointer after `delete` as another pointer can be pointing to the same object.

Comment: @hmjd - *Having a guarded delete does provide a 100% guarantee* -- I think you mean something along the lines of "does not guarantee".

Comment: @NikosChantziaras - With one exception, there is absolutely no reason to guard `delete`. That one exception is if you have overloaded `operator delete` so that it emulates the behavior of `free` in the bad old days, prior to the first C standard. Back then, freeing a null pointer did cause all kinds of havoc. This is the 21st century. Both `free` and `delete` (sans override) are now required to allow a null pointer as input, and to do absolutely nothing when told to free/delete a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assign anything to the pointer (in other words if you don't initialize it) then its value is undefined. It's not `NULL` (well, it could be `NULL` by pure chance, but that chance is slim to none.) Only `static` variables are automatically zero-initialized.

To make a long story short, initialize it to `NULL` in the constructor:

```
GPUMD::GPUMD()
: atoms(NULL)
{ }
```

Or, if you don't like initializers for POD types (why not?), then:

```
GPUMD::GPUMD()
{ atoms = NULL; }
```